# Cropper.js - Export image in certain width and height

Tags: javascript, cropperjs

I´m using the jquery version of the [cropper.js](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs#options). The script works fine so far.

But one thing I can´t get done. I want to have my cropped pictures in an aspect ratio of 16 / 9 with the width of 280px and the height of 158px.

Is that possible with that script?

I have following options and none of them seems to fit my needs:

```
minContainerWidth
Type: Number
Default: 200
The minimum width of the container.

minContainerHeight
Type: Number
Default: 100
The minimum height of the container.

minCanvasWidth
Type: Number
Default: 0
The minimum width of the canvas (image wrapper).

minCanvasHeight
Type: Number
Default: 0
The minimum height of the canvas (image wrapper).

minCropBoxWidth
Type: Number
Default: 0
The minimum width of the crop box.

Note: This size is relative to the page, not the image.

minCropBoxHeight
Type: Number
Default: 0
The minimum height of the crop box.

Note: This size is relative to the page, not the image.
```